# Javascript - Conditional sum in a table

Tags: javascript

I have to add the table values after much thinking I found a solution
But my teacher did not like it, do you have a more elegant way of doing it?

my code: https://pastebin.com/0ZQBgU7b

my solution:

```
const $ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
$('.total')[0].textContent =
[...$('.ages')]
.map(td => parseInt(td.textContent))
.filter(ages => ages >= 18)
.reduce((total, ages) => total + ages, 0);
```

P.S. 
My teacher did not like it.

Comment: It's completely unclear what you're asking - the only thing clear is that your teacher definitely didn't like it.

Comment: Tell your teacher you can explain it to him, but you can't help him understand it. Your solution is fine. What didn't he like?

Comment: Didn't like it, or didn't understand it?

Comment: He said that it is not an elegant solution

Comment: I'm really curious to see what his solution was. Maybe he didn't like that you used jquery?

Comment: I think your solution is quite good. I always like use of map, filter, reduce instead of a for loop. Did he say what he didn't like about it? Despite what he said, It is quite elegant

Comment: tkanks, Explain each command and my logic. I do not know what else to do!

Comment: @mkaatman it's strange, the question is tagged as jquery, but it's never used.

Answer (score 3):

You are using 3 loops, where one would be enough. The map and the filter is not needed here:

```
const $ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
$('.total')[0].textContent =
[...$('.ages')].reduce((total, ages) => 
    total + (parseInt(ages, 10) >= 18 ? parseInt(ages, 10) : 0), 0);
```

Using `Array.from()` instead of the spread operater could also be a good idea in this case.

```
Array.from($('.ages')).reduce(...)
```

Comment: It would also be worthy if you can share a link to explain this syntax `...$('.ages')`

Comment: That's the OP's code, I think he knows it already. Anyways, it's the spread operator. @RajshekarReddy

Comment: @RajshekarReddy I couldnt remember what it was called. I googled "javascript three dots" - [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Comment: @Jamiec that gave me a good laugh... "javascript three dots" this will surely stick into my mind than the `spread operator` Thanks buddy..